# I have error in cmake make make install fmm

Tags: c++, cmake, cygwin, mingw

I want to install fast map matching  [fmm](https://fmm-wiki.github.io/docs/installation/windows.html) on windows (win7)

and cmake has an error:  after command "cmake .."

```
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/c++.exe - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
 The C++ compiler

   "/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/c++.exe"

 It's not able to compile a simple test program.

 It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /cygdrive/e/fmm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

   Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make.exe -f Makefile cmTC_c3891/fast && /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3891.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3891.dir/build
   make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/fmm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
   Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3891.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
   /cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/c++.exe   -O3 -DSPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL=SPDLOG_LEVEL_TRACE  -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3891.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /cygdrive/e/fmm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
   c++.exe: error: /cygdrive/e/fmm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx: No such file or directory
   c++.exe: fatal error: no input files
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3891.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 1
   make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/fmm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
   make: *** [cmTC_c3891/fast] Error 2
 CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:31 (project)
```

and because cmake not success, make -j8 has error

```
make -j8
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

***update***:cmake has successed,the error is that i don't install enough librarys.
but i have error in make and make install

```
E:/anaconda/include/pyport.h:726:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  726 | #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cpl_progress.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/ogrsf_frmts.h:34,
                 from /cygdrive/e/fmm/src/core/geometry.hpp:14,
                 from /cygdrive/e/fmm/build/python/CMakeFiles/pyfmm.dir/fmmPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3392:
/usr/include/cpl_port.h:156:12: fatal error: direct.h: No such file or directory
  156 | #  include <direct.h>
```

i have tried to switch anaconda to the 64 bit ,it has the same error

Comment: Check your CMake Compiler in  CMakeCache.txt

Comment: Possibly due to using a mix of cygwin and mingw? Try using the windows version of cmake

Comment: AV programs tend to interfere with timely creation of files.

Comment: Maybe you will find more information in CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log